# Google script getting error while putting multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have pasted example below

code:

```
    function ck() {

    //assigning variables

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
    var valsr7 = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 3).getValue();
    var valsr30 = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 4).getValue();
    var valsrn = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 5).getValue();
    var valINC7 = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 6).getValue();
    var valINC30 = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 7).getValue();
    var valINCn = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 8).getValue();
    var service = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2).getValue();
    var now = new Date();
    var wk = now.getWeek();

    //now assigning values to variable
    var A = valsr7;
    var B = valsr30;
    var C = valsrn;
    var D = valINC7;
    var E = valINC30;
    var F = valINCn;
    var AB = AB;

    if (service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A ==0 && B == 0 ){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "prathamesh.padosakar.ext@lafargeholcim.com",
    subject : "Open Tickets Global-C&k-T2 - Week-"+wk+"",
    htmlBody: "Dear ABC, "+


    "<p>Not assigned to any one = "+C+""+


    "<P>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+" "+

    "<p>Not updated more than 7 Days = "+D+" "+
    "<p>Not Updated more than 30 Days = "+E+""+
    "<p>Not assigned to any one = "+F+""+



    "<p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+" "+
           "<p>Best Regards,"+
          "<br>Global Service Desk "+,
    cc: "techno.pratham94@gmail.com"})
  }

    if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A == 0){

    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "prathamesh.padosakar.ext@lafargeholcim.com",
    subject : "Open Tickets Global-C&k-T2 - Week-"+wk+"",
    htmlBody: "Dear ABC, "+


    "<p>Not Updated more than 30 Days = "+B+""+
    "<p>Not assigned to any one = "+C+""+

    "<P>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+" "+

    "<p>Not updated more than 7 Days = "+D+" "+
    "<p>Not Updated more than 30 Days = "+E+""+
    "<p>Not assigned to any one = "+F+""+


    "<p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+" "+
    "<p>Best Regards,"+
    "<br>Global Service Desk "+,
    cc: "techno.pratham94@gmail.com"
                      });


    }
    else {

   }   
    if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && B == 0){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "prathamesh.padosakar.ext@lafargeholcim.com",
    subject : "Open Tickets Global-C&k-T2 - Week-"+wk+"",
    htmlBody: "Dear ABC, "+

    "<p>Not updated more than 7 Days = "+A+" "+

    "<p>Not assigned to any one = "+C+""+

    "<P>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+" "+

    "<p>Not updated more than 7 Days = "+D+" "+
    "<p>Not Updated more than 30 Days = "+E+""+
    "<p>Not assigned to any one = "+F+""+


    "<p>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+" "+
    "<p>Best Regards,"+
    "<br>Global Service Desk "+,

    cc: "techno.pratham94@gmail.com"
    });


  }



    else {

  }
```

when i pass condition through `if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A == 0)` and `if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && B == 0)` it gives me single output output or correct output . when i pass condition `if (service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A ==0 && B == 0 )` it give me output of all 3 conditions which are mention below.

`if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A == 0)` and `if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && B == 0)` and `if (service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A ==0 && B == 0 )`

Please help i want single output when i pass condition `if (service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A ==0 && B == 0 )`.

Answer (score 0):

Change condition

```
if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A == 0){
```

to

```
if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A == 0 && B != 0){
```

and change condition

```
if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && B == 0){
```

to

```
if(service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && B == 0 && A != 0){
```

Then you will have one output for `if (service == 'Global-Servicenow-Support-T2' && A ==0 && B == 0 )`